# How to prioritize pages over posts when searching?

Tags: wordpress

So I'm new to Wordpress and as such I'm not entirely sure how things work with it. But one of the problems I am having is that the default search feature treats Pages and Posts the same.

For example, I have Page called Java, then I have several posts titled Learning Java #... If I search Java, the Page comes up as the last item and the posts come before it. I'm wondering if there is a way to tweak the search so I have Pages listed first.

Also, I've googled this a bit and have seen some supposed PHP fixes to this problem, but as I said, I'm new to Wordpress so I'm not sure where exactly I'll be editing in PHP. Any help would be appreciated, and if you comment, please treat me as a real beginner and break things down so I can understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this code in your `function.php`:

```
function change_search_result_order($query) {
// Check if current page is search page
    if ($query->is_search) {
// Specify orderby and order, ordering will be by slug of post_type: pAge > pOst
        $query->set('orderby', 'post_type');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    };
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_search_result_order');
```

By default search function work with all post type, and you can specify in which you want to make a search:

```
$query->set('post_type', array('page','post'));
```

hook `pre_get_posts` will fired before get any posts, so we need to modify it. And set some arguments, to get posts with specific criteria.