# How do I prioritize posts over pages in a wordpress/genesis search result page?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

How do I prioritize posts over pages in a wordpress/genesis search result page? Similar to this code, except I'd like posts to show before pages and I can't seem to fully adjust this code to do it:

```
function change_search_result_order($query) {
// Check if current page is search page
    if ($query->is_search) {
// Specify orderby and order, ordering will be by slug of post_type: pAge > pOst
        $query->set('orderby', 'post_type');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    };
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_search_result_order');
```

this code block was also mentioned, but I can't seem to find where it fits--if I could, would it be as simple as switching page and post?

```
$query->set('post_type', array('page','post'));
```

Original source: [How to prioritize pages over posts when searching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669757/how-to-prioritize-pages-over-posts-when-searching)

thanks in advance!
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you break down the code that was given in that other answer, you can clearly see what it's doing.

- The custom function is called on `pre_get_posts`, which is before any posts are fetched.
- Inside the function, it makes sure it's a `search` query, and won't fire on other pages or page templates.
- It sets the `post_types` to `page` and `post`, thereby removing any custom post types.
- It changes the order of the post to order by the name of the `post_type`
- It changes the order of the posts to be Ascending or Descending.

Add the `post_types` in there, so that way if you use another plugin that adds CPTs or add your own, they won't be included (such as events or staff members).

Since WP 4.0 the `$query` accepts `type` as an `orderby` parameter. Note that `post_type` works as well, but the default non-aliased value is `type`.

Change the order to `Desc` since you want [PO]sts before [PA]ges

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_search_result_order' );
function change_search_result_order($query){
    if( $query->is_search ){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page', 'post' ) );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'type' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    };

    return $query;
}
```

Stick that in your functions.php file and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it all--I'm really new at functions. I didn't know the meanings of [ASC]ending versus [DESC]ending, but it makes sense now. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha no worries, I've been a WP/PHP dev for years now and sometimes I still have to pause and think about which way things will go in `ASC` vs `DESC`. Cheers!